# rails asset pipeline asset group not precompiling datatables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, datatables, asset-pipeline

I started building a rails project that uses jquery-datatables-rails.  When I put that into my Gemfile I did NOT put it into the assets group.  Everything worked fine in development.  When I went to put it into production I re-read the documentation and saw that it should be in the assets group so I moved that line in my Gemfile.  Then I performed a rake assets:precompile and then ran rails server -e production.

The datatable doesn't work.  In fact, the only way I can make it work is to take that line out of the assets group in my Gemfile and run in development mode.  I've read a lot of conflicting information on the Internet about this.

Did I screw anything up by moving the line from outside the assets group into the assets group?  I would like to be able to run this in production and I want to have a Gemfile that is consistent with the jquery-datatables-rails documentation.

Comment: Need more information about the failure mode.  If you are using WEBrick, then it will not be serving static, precompiled assets at all, unless you have `config.serve_static_assets = true` in production.rb.  Are you seeing routing errors in the console?  Does it work fine in production when the gem is outside the assets group?

Comment: I am using WEBrick and I don't see any errors in the console.  It looks like there isn't any javascript loading for jquery-datatables-rails.  I have config.serve_static_assets set to true in my production.rb file.  I know that at least some of the static assets are getting served up because I have twitter-bootstrap-rails in my assets group and that is working as expected in production.  I have confirmed that it works either way in development until I run rake assets:precompile.  Then it wont work either way.

Comment: So to sum up, whether gem 'jquery-datatables-rails' is in the assets group or not, it doesn't work in production.  It will work both ways in development until I run rake assets:precompile at which point it will no longer work regardless of whether that line is in assets or not.  Confusing?

Comment: So if it works in development until you run `rake assets:precompile`, then how do you recover from that?  Delete everything in `public/assets`?  Running that rake task should not affect anything in development.  If it is, it suggests that something is amiss with the setup of your assets pipeline.  Have you made any other changes to the environment files?  Have you tried making a trivial Rails test app to see if you have the same problem there?

Comment: I whipped up an app just to compare the development.rb and production.rb file to a baseline.  There is no diff in the development file.  In production the only diff is serve_static_assets=true.  I actually have this project in its current, semi-working, state up on Github.  https://github.com/blackfist/CIFGlue  I really appreciate the time you're taking with me on this.

Comment: I looked at the code for datatables and copied a bit of it.  Compiled the assets and searched for the code in public/assets/application.js  I found it, which tells me that it is compiling properly.  Still doesn't help understand why it works in dev but not prod and why once the assets are compiled it wont work in dev again.  Even deleting public/assets does not make dev work.

Comment: I played around with your app a bit and had the same problem.  I think it might be related to the issues here https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/5145, but I could not get to the bottom of it.  I think it is possible that `assets:precompile` is failing to include the needed jquery for datatables/bootstrap.  This is based on the error message I see when I set `config.assets.compile = false` in production:  `ActionView::Template::Error (couldn't find file 'dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A while back in response to a different problem that I was having, I moved `require twitter/bootstrap` above `require jquery` in app/assets/javascripts/application.js.  As a result the javascript wasn't working right.  Moving it into the right place solved the problem and inexplicably did not cause the old problem to return.

So the fix is, make sure that jquery is at the top of your application.js file.